# Invoke Querydsl to read the database tables and generate the Java classes

Tags: java, oracle, querydsl

i use oracle database, and i need to invoke Querydsl to read the database tables and generate the **Java classes**.
i don't understand how to do that,like below

```
java.sql.Connection conn = ...;
MetaDataExporter exporter = newMetaDataExporter();
exporter.setPackageName("com.myproject.mydomain");
exporter.setTargetFolder(newFile("src/main/java"));
exporter.export(conn.getMetaData());
```

So how to do that ? thanks

Comment: Did you try this code and did it add new sources to src/main/java? Also consider using a proper target folder like suggested here http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.9.0/reference/html/ch02s03.html

Comment: thanks for your reply but now i need to join between multiple tables